# Does a disk failing a test mean trouble? How serious is the situation?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, smart

So I have two drives in my computer, a HDD (Seagate Barracuda ST2000DM001) and an SSD (Corsair Force 3 120GB). They are both 3 years old and I thought they should last much longer, especially the HDD. Though I do admit my computer had trouble for quite some time with rough shutdowns because of trouble with the PSU.

But when I checked their SMART data they both have "Pre-Fail" in some fields. Now I know not all fields are as important but I had a hard time finding correct interpretations (especially for the SSD).

What is more, the HDD seems to fail self-tests. I tried with multiple programs, including Seagate's Seatools tool and smartctl (Bash).

So here are the questions: How serious is the actual situation? Are the drives really likely to fail? If so, should I just make backups and wait for it to happen or is it better to completely replace them ASAP?

Thank you for your time

SSD's smartctl output:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-68-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SandForce Driven SSDs
Device Model:     Corsair Force 3 SSD
Serial Number:    123579030000148000CF
LU WWN Device Id: 0 000000 000000000
Firmware Version: 5.02
User Capacity:    120 034 123 776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS, ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Nov 21 16:21:08 2015 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x02) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  48) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0021) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   102   102   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0/5234531
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       11967h+34m+04.340s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3278
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       226
177 Wear_Range_Delta        0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       5
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   128   129   000    Old_age   Always       -       128 (0 127 0 129 0)
195 ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/5234531
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
201 Unc_Soft_Read_Err_Rate  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/5234531
204 Soft_ECC_Correct_Rate   0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/5234531
230 Life_Curve_Status       0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 SandForce_Internal      0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       12621
234 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       12514
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       12514
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       29432

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test Log not supported

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

HDD's smartctl output:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-68-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 (AF)
Device Model:     ST2000DM001-9YN164
Serial Number:    W2F0H8WJ
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0521c0222
Firmware Version: CC4B
User Capacity:    2 000 398 934 016 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Nov 21 16:21:22 2015 CET

==> WARNING: A firmware update for this drive may be available,
see the following Seagate web pages:
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207931en
http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/223651en

SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 118) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  609) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 268) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3085) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   117   092   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       126852928
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   092   092   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   096   096   020    Old_age   Always       -       4401
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   099   099   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       1920
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   075   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       31129310
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   087   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       11477
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   020    Old_age   Always       -       3241
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       396
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3 3 6
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   071   071   000    Old_age   Always       -       29
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   061   055   045    Old_age   Always       -       39 (0 3 39 26 0)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       175
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   080   080   000    Old_age   Always       -       40743
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   039   045   000    Old_age   Always       -       39 (128 0 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       56
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       56
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       7490h+56m+13.583s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       63675395780589
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       174517029624904

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 28 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 28 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10950 hours (456 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:44.600  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  2f 00 01 10 00 00 e0 00      02:37:44.499  READ LOG EXT
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:41.728  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:41.207  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:41.121  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 27 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10950 hours (456 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:41.728  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:41.207  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:41.121  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:41.025  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:41.025  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 26 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10950 hours (456 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:38.091  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:38.090  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 58 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:38.083  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:38.047  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:38.047  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 25 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10950 hours (456 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:35.195  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 50 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:35.186  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:35.138  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:34.971  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 60 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:34.861  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 24 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 10950 hours (456 days + 6 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:28.411  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:28.410  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 38 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:19.842  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 18 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:17.597  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 68 ff ff ff 4f 00      02:37:16.028  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       60%     11477         481008573
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     11419         481008573
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     11419         481008573
# 4  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     11411         481008573
# 5  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     11407         481008573
# 6  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     11407         481008573
# 7  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     11407         481008573
# 8  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     11406         481008573
# 9  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     11406         481008573
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9233         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6265         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Clone the failing drive to a new drive before it fails completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s the “Type” column. It doesn’t indicate a status of any kind, but instead whether degradation of an attribute is normal (from old age) or an indicator of impending failure.

That being said, your HDD is clearly just about gone. It has a large amount of reallocated sectors, indicating surface damage.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. So would you say the SSD is still okay?